# Targeting all process names that start with "flashplayer" or "flashplayer_X_sa"

Tags: c#

I want to be able to target all process that show in the task manager for setting the priority levels, specifically **I want to target all process that start with "flashplayer" or "flashplayer_X_sa"** the **X stands for any number**.

Here is what I got...

```
namespace Processhighlevel
{
    class PUBG_RealTime
    {
        static string processName = "flashplayer_18_sa";

        static ProcessPriorityClass newPriority = ProcessPriorityClass.High;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {



        Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName);

        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
        PutDebug(processes.Length + " process detected \n");

        foreach (Process proc in processes)
        {



            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
            Console.WriteLine("Set Priority for id: " + proc.Id + " to " +  
            newPriority.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Enjoy!");
            proc.PriorityClass = newPriority;


            PutDebug("Changed priority for \n" + proc.Id);

        }

        PutDebug("No more processes.. \n");

        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit... \n");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }


    static bool debug = false;
    static int debugInc = 1;
    static void PutDebug(string info = "")
    {
        if (debug)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" " + debugInc + ": " + info);
            debugInc++;
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Instead of `Process.GetProcessesByName(processName)` do `Process.GetProcesses().Where(p=> p.ProcessName.StartsWith("flashplayer"))` and add the extra conditions in that where.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Linq` and `Regex` for this.

This is how I would do it:

Don't forget to import

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

I'll use regex to match all the process to the pattern you want:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<![\w\d])flashplayer(_([0-9]+)_sa)*(?![\w\d])");
// Get all processes and use Linq to filter on the regex pattern
var processes = Process.GetProcesses().Where(p => regex.IsMatch(p.ProcessName));

foreach (var proc in processes)
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: This regex would not match the ones that start with "flashplayer" only. However, as I see the question, the "_anyNumber_sa" part is reduntant if OP wants to match on anything that starts with "flashplayer" anyways.

Comment: @Philzax You are correct, I updated my answer, let me know what you think about it!

Comment: Ye, but still reduntant IMO. Op just wants the ones that START with "flashplayer" or "flashplayer_anyNumber_sa", which means it's redundant to match on anything but "flashplayer". Also this regex currently does not ensure that this match is at the beginning of the processname, like OP specified.